# Gradle 5 JUnit BOM and Spring Boot Incorrect Versions

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, junit, junit5

I am using Gradle 5's BOM (Bill of Materials) [feature](https://docs.gradle.org/5.0/userguide/managing_transitive_dependencies.html#sec:bom_import). This is how I describe it for my JUnit 5 dependencies:

```
testImplementation(enforcedPlatform("org.junit:junit-bom:5.4.0")) // JUnit 5 BOM
testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api")
testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine")
testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params")
```

My assumption is that providing the BOM will resolve the versions of the dependencies to `5.4.0`. However, they get resolved to `5.1.1`. I am not sure why. (I also request `enforcedPlatform()` to lock the specified version)

[image]

Inspecting [JUnit 5's BOM](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/junit/junit-bom/5.4.0/junit-bom-5.4.0.pom) we see that all `org.junit.jupiter` dependencies are listed with version `5.4.0` (resolving to 5.1.1 in the project) and all `org.junit.platform` dependencies are listed with version `1.4.0` which resolve correctly in the project.

I am not sure what I am missing and was hoping to get some help here. Thanks!

**EDIT:**

I used Sormuras response and moved all BOMs at the top of the `dependencies {}` block but was still not getting version `5.4.0`. Then I suspected it might be coming from the [Gradle Spring Dependency Management](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/gradle-plugin/reference/html/#managing-dependencies) plugin that I use, so when I commented it out, I got version JUnit 5.4.0. How do I disable JUnit coming from the Gradle Spring Dependency Management plugin?

[image: Gradle Spring Dependency Management plugin]

**FINALLY:**

I decided to use the [Spring Boot Dependencies BOM](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-dependencies) directly and remove the Gradle plugin:

`implementation(platform("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:2.0.5.RELEASE"))`

I imagine the plugin was created for those version of Gradle before Gradle 5 where you couldn't use a BOM file. Now with the BOM support I can directly include it. This way my version of JUnit is as I have specified it in the `enforcedPlatform()` block.

I accepted Sam Brannen's answer below because he explains well how the issue occurs and what solves it and I think it's relevant for those who use older versions of Gradle.

Comment: What does `./gradlew dependencyInsight --dependency junit-jupiter-api --configuration testCompileClasspath` print?

Comment: @MarcPhilipp https://imgur.com/dGBFyxf

Answer (score 55, accepted):

> How do I disable JUnit coming from the Gradle Spring Dependency Management plugin?

For starters, if you are using the dependency management plugin from Spring, you should not be importing the `junit-bom` since that results in duplicate (and potentially conflicting) management of those dependencies.

Aside from that, whenever you use the dependency management plugin from Spring and want to override a managed version, you have to do it by overriding the exact name of the version defined in the BOM used by the plugin.

This is documented in Spring Boot [for Gradle](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.2.RELEASE/gradle-plugin/reference/html/#managing-dependencies-customizing) and [for Maven](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.2.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-maven-parent-pom).

For Spring Boot the name of the JUnit Jupiter version is "junit-jupiter.version". You can find the names of all managed versions for Spring Boot 2.1.2 [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v2.1.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-dependencies/pom.xml).

So, in Gradle you would override it as follows.

`ext['junit-jupiter.version'] = '5.4.0'`.

You can see that I have done exactly that [here](https://github.com/sbrannen/spring-events/blob/d803b0fe2e007f2264973d135c4b5ac814f49477/build.gradle#L38).

With Maven you would override it as follows.

```
<properties>
    <junit-jupiter.version>5.4.0</junit-jupiter.version>
</properties>
```

Further background information here: https://docs.spring.io/platform/docs/current/reference/html/getting-started-overriding-versions.html

Comment: Thank you @Sam Brannen! I have to say though that I'm not very happy how using `enforcedPlatform()` doesn't achieve what you'll think it should achieve. I'll use your advice and thanks for it!

Answer (score 7):

JUnit 5.4.0 simplified its artifacts, and now delivered a single artifact for Jupiter - `org.junit:junit-jupiter`. I.e., you should simplify your Gradle file too:

```
testImplementation(enforcedPlatform("org.junit:junit-bom:5.4.0")) // JUnit 5 BOM
testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter")
```

Comment: that's nice! I get `JUnit Jupiter` version 5.4.0 but I can see individual versions for JUnit Jupiter API, Engine and Params are still resolving to `5.1.1`

Comment: I replaced:

```
sdfsdfs
````

<code>
testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.8.2'
 testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.8.2'
 testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:5.8.2'
</code>

with:

Answer (score 3):

Ensure to include JUnit's BOM *before* other BOMs that also refer to JUnit. First BOM wins and locks version of all later artifacts.

See this issue for a similar setup using Maven and Spring Boot: https://github.com/sormuras/junit-platform-maven-plugin/issues/29#issuecomment-456958188

Comment: Thanks! I moved all BOMs at the top of the `dependencies {}` block but was still not getting version `5.4.0`. Then I suspected it might be coming from the Gradle Spring Boot plugin that I use, so when I commented it out, I got version `5.4.0`.

How do I disable JUnit coming from the Gradle Spring Boot plugin https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/org.springframework.boot

Comment: What does SO answer to this new/follow-up question? ;) Maybe here you can getter quicker help: https://discuss.gradle.org