# why auto dependency is error version?(java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.junit.jupiter.api.MethodOrdererContext)

Tags: java, maven, junit5

#### I want to know why  is not same to junit-jupiter-engine-5.4.0.pom defined.

when I explicit declaration junit-jupiter-api and junit-platform-engine version  same as junit-jupiter-engine-5.4.0.pom,the problem be solved.

### pom:

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
      <version>5.4.0</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

### problem:

junit-jupiter-engine-5.4.0.pom dependency is

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.apiguardian</groupId>
      <artifactId>apiguardian-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-platform-engine</artifactId>
      <version>1.4.0</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
      <version>5.4.0</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

but I run `mvn dependency:tree` ,result is this:

```
[INFO] +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:jar:5.4.0:test
[INFO] |  +- org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:jar:1.0.0:test
[INFO] |  +- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-engine:jar:1.3.2:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-commons:jar:1.3.2:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.opentest4j:opentest4j:jar:1.1.1:test
[INFO] |  \- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:jar:5.3.2:test
```

Build Tool:`maven3.5.4`

Comment: Are you using Spring Boot or something that manages your dependency versions?

Comment: Potentially a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/54605523/388980

Comment: @Sam Brannen：
Thank you .
I use ```org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:2.1.2.RELEASE```.
I find denpency of ```org.junit.jupiter``` in ```spring-boot-test-2.1.2.RELEASE.pom```:
```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
  <version>5.3.2</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
  <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
```
So, that's the reason.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gradle 5 JUnit BOM and Spring Boot Incorrect Versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54598484/gradle-5-junit-bom-and-spring-boot-incorrect-versions)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is duplicate of [Gradle 5 JUnit BOM and Spring Boot Incorrect Versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54598484/gradle-5-junit-bom-and-spring-boot-incorrect-versions/54605523#54605523).

The solution is to add the following to your Maven POM.

```
<properties>
    <junit-jupiter.version>5.4.0</junit-jupiter.version>
</properties>
```

Comment: This still working for the 5.8.0-M1 version

Comment: thanks, works fine!

Answer (score 0):

I have faced similar issue after updating spring boot dependencies to latest version and updating Juiper engine version to 5.6.1 has resolved my issue.

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
<artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
<version>5.6.1</version>
<scope>test</scope>
```