# How to catch Hibernate ConstraintViolationException (or Spring DataIntegrityViolationException?) in Spring Boot with JUnit 5

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, junit5

I considered naming this “The Heisenberg Uncertainty Corollary for Java Exceptions”, but that was (a) too unwieldy, and (b) not sufficiently descriptive.

BLUF: I’m trying to catch, in a JUnit 5 test against a Spring Boot application, the exception thrown when a tuple is persisted to a database table with a constraint violation (duplicate value in column marked “unique”). I can catch the exception in try-catch block, but not using JUnit’s “assertThrows()”.

Elaboration

For ease-of-replication, I have narrowed down my code to only the entity and repository, and two tests (one works, the other is the reason for this post). Also for ease-of-replication, I am using H2 as the database.

I had read that there are potential transactional scope issues which can cause the constraint-generated exception to not be thrown within the scope of the invoking method. I confirmed this with a simple try-catch block around the statement “foos.aave(foo);” in shouldThrowExceptionOnSave() (without the “tem.flush()” statement).

I decided to use TestEntityManager.flush() to force the transaction to commit/end, and was able to successfully catch an exception in the try-catch block. However, it was not the expected DataIntegrityViolationException, but PersistenceException.

I attempted to use a similar mechanism (i.e., employ TestEntityManager.flush() to force the issue in the assertThrows() statement. But, “no joy”.

When I try “assertThrows(PersistenceException.class,…”, the method terminates with a DataIntegrityViolationException.

When I try “assertThrows(DataIntegrityViolationException.class,…”, I actually get a JUnit error message, indicating that the expected DataIntegrityViolationException didn’t match the actual exception. Which is…javax.persistence.PersistenceException!

Any help/insight would be greatly appreciated.

Add Note: The try-catch block in shouldThrowExceptionOnSave() is just to see what exception is caught.

Entity Class

```
package com.test.foo;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Foo {

    @Id
    @Column(name     = "id",
            nullable = false,
            unique   = true)
    private String id;
    @Column(name     = "name",
            nullable = false,
            unique   = true)
    private String name;

    public Foo() {
        id   = "Default ID";
        name = "Default Name";
    }

    public Foo(String id, String name) {
        this.id   = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getId() { return id;}

    public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }

    public String getName() { return name; }
}
```

Repository Interface

```
package com.test.foo;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

public interface FooRepository extends CrudRepository<Foo, String> { }
```

Repository Test Class

```
package com.test.foo;

import org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.AfterEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.TestEntityManager;
import org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException;

import javax.persistence.PersistenceException;
import java.util.Optional;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertThrows;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertTrue;

@DataJpaTest
public class FooRepositoryITest {

    @Autowired
    private TestEntityManager tem;

    @Autowired
    private FooRepository foos;

    private static final int    NUM_ROWS  = 25;
    private static final String BASE_ID   = "->Test Id";
    private static final String BASE_NAME = "->Test Name";

    @BeforeEach
    public void insertFooTuples() {
        Foo foo;

        for (int i=0; i<NUM_ROWS; i++) {
            foo = new Foo(i+BASE_ID, i+BASE_NAME);
            tem.persist(foo);
        }
        tem.flush();
    }

    @AfterEach
    public void removeFooTuples() {
        foos.findAll()
                .forEach(tem::remove);
        tem.flush();
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldSaveNewTyple() {
        Optional<Foo> newFoo;
        String        newId   = "New Test Id";
        String        newName = "New Test Name";
        Foo           foo     = new Foo(newId, newName);

        foos.save(foo);
        tem.flush();

        newFoo = foos.findById(newId);
        assertTrue(newFoo.isPresent(), "Failed to add Foo tuple");
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldThrowExceptionOnSave() {
        Optional<Foo> newFoo;
        String        newId   = "New Test Id";
        String        newName = "New Test Name";
        Foo           foo     = new Foo(newId, newName);

        foo.setName(foos.findById(1+BASE_ID).get().getName());

        try {
            foos.save(foo);
            tem.flush();
        } catch(PersistenceException e) {
            System.out.println("\n\n**** IN CATCH BLOCK ****\n\n");
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }

//        assertThrows(DataIntegrityViolationException.class,
//        assertThrows(ConstraintViolationException.class,
        assertThrows(PersistenceException.class,
                () -> { foos.save(foo);
                        tem.flush();
                      } );
    }
}
```

build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.1.3.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

group = 'com.test'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
    implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    runtimeOnly('com.h2database:h2')
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'junit'
        exclude group: 'org.hamcrest'
    }
    testImplementation('org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.4.0')
    testImplementation('com.h2database:h2')
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Output with "assertThrows(PersitenceException, ...)"

```
2019-02-25 14:55:12.747  WARN 15796 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 23505, SQLState: 23505
2019-02-25 14:55:12.747 ERROR 15796 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Unique index or primary key violation: "UK_A7S9IMMDPCXHLN2D4JHLAY516_INDEX_1 ON PUBLIC.FOO(NAME) VALUES ('1->Test Name', 2)"; SQL statement:
insert into foo (name, id) values (?, ?) [23505-197]

**** IN CATCH BLOCK ****

javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
.
. (some debug output removed for brevity)
.
2019-02-25 14:55:12.869  WARN 15796 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 23505, SQLState: 23505
2019-02-25 14:55:12.869 ERROR 15796 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Unique index or primary key violation: "UK_A7S9IMMDPCXHLN2D4JHLAY516_INDEX_1 ON PUBLIC.FOO(NAME) VALUES ('1->Test Name', 2)"; SQL statement:
insert into foo (name, id) values (?, ?) [23505-197]
2019-02-25 14:55:12.877  INFO 15796 --- [           main] o.s.t.c.transaction.TransactionContext   : Rolled back transaction for test: [DefaultTestContext@313ac989 testClass = FooRepositoryITest, testInstance = com.test.foo.FooRepositoryITest@71d44a3, testMethod = shouldThrowExceptionOnSave@FooRepositoryITest, testException = org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint ["UK_A7S9IMMDPCXHLN2D4JHLAY516_INDEX_1 ON PUBLIC.FOO(NAME) VALUES ('1->Test Name', 2)"; SQL statement:
insert into foo (name, id) values (?, ?) [23505-197]]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement, mergedContextConfiguration = [MergedContextConfiguration@4562e04d testClass = FooRepositoryITest, locations = '{}', classes = '{class com.test.foo.FooApplication}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTestContextBootstrapper=true}', contextCustomizers = set[org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.OverrideAutoConfigurationContextCustomizerFactory$DisableAutoConfigurationContextCustomizer@527e5409, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.filter.TypeExcludeFiltersContextCustomizer@351584c0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@8b41920b, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizerFactory$Customizer@2a32de6c, [ImportsContextCustomizer@2a65fe7c key = [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.CacheAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.jpa.JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.JdbcTemplateAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.liquibase.LiquibaseAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.transaction.TransactionAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.jdbc.TestDatabaseAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.TestEntityManagerAutoConfiguration]], org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@147ed70f, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@15b204a1, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0], contextLoader = 'org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader', parent = [null]], attributes = map[[empty]]]

org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint ["UK_A7S9IMMDPCXHLN2D4JHLAY516_INDEX_1 ON PUBLIC.FOO(NAME) VALUES ('1->Test Name', 2)"; SQL statement:
insert into foo (name, id) values (?, ?) [23505-197]]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
```

Output with "assertThrows(DataIntegrityViolationException, ...)

```
2019-02-25 14:52:16.880  WARN 2172 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 23505, SQLState: 23505
2019-02-25 14:52:16.880 ERROR 2172 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Unique index or primary key violation: "UK_A7S9IMMDPCXHLN2D4JHLAY516_INDEX_1 ON PUBLIC.FOO(NAME) VALUES ('1->Test Name', 2)"; SQL statement:
insert into foo (name, id) values (?, ?) [23505-197]

**** IN CATCH BLOCK ****

javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
.
. (some debug output removed for brevity)
.
insert into foo (name, id) values (?, ?) [23505-197]
2019-02-25 14:52:16.974  INFO 2172 --- [           main] o.s.t.c.transaction.TransactionContext   : Rolled back transaction for test: [DefaultTestContext@313ac989 testClass = FooRepositoryITest, testInstance = com.test.foo.FooRepositoryITest@71d44a3, testMethod = shouldThrowExceptionOnSave@FooRepositoryITest, testException = org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: Unexpected exception type thrown ==> expected: <org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException> but was: <javax.persistence.PersistenceException>, mergedContextConfiguration = [MergedContextConfiguration@4562e04d testClass = FooRepositoryITest, locations = '{}', classes = '{class com.test.foo.FooApplication}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTestContextBootstrapper=true}', contextCustomizers = set[org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.OverrideAutoConfigurationContextCustomizerFactory$DisableAutoConfigurationContextCustomizer@527e5409, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.filter.TypeExcludeFiltersContextCustomizer@351584c0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@8b41920b, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizerFactory$Customizer@2a32de6c, [ImportsContextCustomizer@2a65fe7c key = [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.CacheAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.jpa.JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.JdbcTemplateAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.liquibase.LiquibaseAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.transaction.TransactionAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.jdbc.TestDatabaseAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.TestEntityManagerAutoConfiguration]], org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@147ed70f, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@15b204a1, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0], contextLoader = 'org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader', parent = [null]], attributes = map[[empty]]]

org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: Unexpected exception type thrown ==> 
Expected :<org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException> 
Actual   :<javax.persistence.PersistenceException>
<Click to see difference>
```

Comment: Is it possible that, because Spring is generating the implementation for the repository interface, that the integration test should not be at the FooRepository level (i.e., no need to test Spring's implementation?), but at the FooService level (which uses FooRepository and is "one level up", where the exceptions can be observed/caught)?

Comment: Based on discussion on another post, "some" level of integration testing is valid against the repository - just not on the out-of-the-box methods (e.g., findAll(), findById(), etc.).

Comment: Testing built-in methods such as `save()` is perfectly valid and even recommended at times in order to ensure the correctness of entity mappings, cascading rules, uniqueness constraints, etc.

Comment: FYI: your build actually does **not**  use JUnit Jupiter 5.4. Rather, it's using JUnit Jupiter 5.3.2 as managed by Spring Boot. See the following issue for the solution. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54598484/gradle-5-junit-bom-and-spring-boot-incorrect-versions/54605523#54605523

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Side Notes

Your project actually does not use JUnit Jupiter 5.4. Rather, it's using JUnit Jupiter 5.3.2 as managed by Spring Boot. See [Gradle 5 JUnit BOM and Spring Boot Incorrect Versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54598484/gradle-5-junit-bom-and-spring-boot-incorrect-versions/54605523#54605523) for the solution.

There is no need to `flush()` in your `@BeforeEach` method.

You should remove your `@AfterEach` method since all changes to the database will be rolled back automatically with the test-managed transaction.

#### Catching a ConstraintViolationException

You actually cannot catch the `ConstraintViolationException` since JPA will wrap it an a `PersistenceException`, but you can verify that a `ConstraintViolationException` *caused* the `PersistenceException`.

To do that, simply rewrite your test as follows.

```
@Test
public void shouldThrowExceptionOnSave() {
    String newId = "New Test Id";
    String newName = "New Test Name";
    Foo foo = new Foo(newId, newName);

    foo.setName(fooRepository.findById(1 + BASE_ID).get().getName());

    PersistenceException exception = assertThrows(PersistenceException.class, () -> {
        fooRepository.save(foo);
        testEntityManager.flush();
    });

    assertTrue(exception.getCause() instanceof ConstraintViolationException);
}
```

#### Catching a DataIntegrityViolationException

If you want to catch an exception from Spring's `DataAccessException` hierarchy — such as `DataIntegrityViolationException`, you have to ensure that the `EntityManager#flush()` method is invoked in such a way that Spring performs exception translation.

Exception translation is performed via Spring's `PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor` which wraps your `@Repository` bean in a proxy in order to catch the exceptions and translate them. Spring Boot registers the `PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor` for you automatically and ensures that your Spring Data JPA repositories are properly proxied.

In your example, you are invoking `flush()` directly on Spring Boot's `TestEntityManager` which does not perform exception translation. That is why you see the raw `javax.persistence.PersistenceException` instead of Spring's `DataIntegrityViolationException`.

If you want to assert that Spring will wrap the `PersistenceException` in a `DataIntegrityViolationException`, you need to do the following.

1. Redeclare your repository as follows. `JpaRepository` gives you access to the `flush()` method directly on your repository.

   `public interface FooRepository extends JpaRepository<Foo, String> {}`
2. In your `shouldThrowExceptionOnSave()` test method, invoke `fooRepository.save(foo); fooRepository.flush();` or `fooRepository.saveAndFlush(foo);`.

If you do so, the following will now pass.

```
@Test
public void shouldThrowExceptionOnSave() {
    String newId = "New Test Id";
    String newName = "New Test Name";
    Foo foo = new Foo(newId, newName);

    foo.setName(fooRepository.findById(1 + BASE_ID).get().getName());

    assertThrows(DataIntegrityViolationException.class, () -> {
        fooRepository.save(foo);
        fooRepository.flush();
        // fooRepository.saveAndFlush(foo);
    });
}
```

Again, the reason this works is that the `flush()` method is now invoked directly on your repository bean which Spring has wrapped in a proxy that catches the  `PersistenceException` and *translates* it into a `DataIntegrityViolationException`.

Comment: Excellent explanation! This helps me solve the problem I had to catch DataIntegrityViolationExceptions.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Sam for his answer. Interestingly, one of Sam's "oh, by-the-way" comments uncovered what seems to be the "real issue" in my code.

Below is the final code (almost), that almost works.

"Almost", because the test execution still fails, and it appears to fail on a constraint violation when attempting to insert a tuple (see snippet from console log below).

```
2019-02-27 09:28:50.237  INFO 4860 --- [           main] o.h.h.i.QueryTranslatorFactoryInitiator  : HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
Hibernate: insert into foo (name, id) values (?, ?)
2019-02-27 09:28:50.311  WARN 4860 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 23505, SQLState: 23505
2019-02-27 09:28:50.311 ERROR 4860 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Unique index or primary key violation: "UK_A7S9IMMDPCXHLN2D4JHLAY516_INDEX_1 ON PUBLIC.FOO(NAME) VALUES ('0->Test Name', 1)"; SQL statement:
insert into foo (name, id) values (?, ?) [23505-197]
2019-02-27 09:28:50.311  INFO 4860 --- [           main] o.s.t.c.transaction.TransactionContext   : Rolled back transaction for test: [DefaultTestContext@1d296da testClass = FooRepositoryITest, testInstance = com.test.foo.FooRepositoryITest@6989da5e, testMethod = shouldThrowExceptionOnSave@FooRepositoryITest, testException = org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint ["UK_A7S9IMMDPCXHLN2D4JHLAY516_INDEX_1 ON PUBLIC.FOO(NAME) VALUES ('0->Test Name', 1)"; SQL statement:
insert into foo (name, id) values (?, ?) [23505-197]]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement, mergedContextConfiguration = [MergedContextConfiguration@7c7a06ec testClass = FooRepositoryITest, locations = '{}', classes = '{class com.test.foo.FooApplication}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTestContextBootstrapper=true}', contextCustomizers = set[org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.OverrideAutoConfigurationContextCustomizerFactory$DisableAutoConfigurationContextCustomizer@45018215, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.filter.TypeExcludeFiltersContextCustomizer@351584c0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@617263ed, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizerFactory$Customizer@2f112965, [ImportsContextCustomizer@75d4a5c2 key = [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.CacheAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.jpa.JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.JdbcTemplateAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.liquibase.LiquibaseAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.transaction.TransactionAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.jdbc.TestDatabaseAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.TestEntityManagerAutoConfiguration]], org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@1f3f4916, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@59d016c9, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0], contextLoader = 'org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader', parent = [null]], attributes = map[[empty]]]

org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint ["UK_A7S9IMMDPCXHLN2D4JHLAY516_INDEX_1 ON PUBLIC.FOO(NAME) VALUES ('0->Test Name', 1)"; SQL statement:
insert into foo (name, id) values (?, ?) [23505-197]]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
```

But, and this is where the "oh, by-the-way" comment comes into play, it's not failing in the actual test. It appears to be failing in *removeFooTuples()*, which is being executed after *shouldThrowExceptionOnSave()* by JUnit. Yet, even though *removeFooTuples()* simply attempts to delete any existing tuples from the table (and, does so successfully in tests where exceptions are not expected/thrown), the console log indicates that an "insert" is being attempted.

If the entirety of *removeFooTuples()* is commented out, and JUnit is allowed to simply drop the table, the test successfully executes to termination with expected results. I had thought the *TestEntityManager.flush()* in *shouldThrowExceptionOnSave()* would have avoided this scenario, but...

```
@DataJpaTest
public class FooRepositoryITest {

    @Autowired
    private TestEntityManager tem;

    @Autowired
    private FooRepository foos;

    private static final int    NUM_ROWS  = 1;
    private static final String BASE_ID   = "->Test Id";
    private static final String BASE_NAME = "->Test Name";

    @BeforeEach
    public void insertFooTuples() {
        Foo foo;

        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_ROWS; i++) {
            foo = new Foo(i + BASE_ID, i + BASE_NAME);
            tem.persist(foo);
        }
        tem.flush();
    }

    /* shouldThrowExceptionOnSave() executes successfully if this
     *  method is commented out
     */
    @AfterEach
    public void removeFooTuples() {
        foos.findAll()
                .forEach(tem::remove);
        tem.flush();
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldThrowExceptionOnSave() {
        String newId   = "New Test Id";
        String newName = "New Test Name";
        Foo    foo     = new Foo(newId, newName);

        foo.setName(foos.findById(0+BASE_ID).get().getName());

        assertThrows(PersistenceException.class, () -> {
                        foos.save(foo);
                        tem.flush();
                    } );
    }
}
```

Comment: Per Spring, the issue appears to be that, once an error occurs, the transaction needs to be rolled back and a new entity manager instance obtained. For now (at least), simply eliminating removeFooTuples() works. But, I thought the idea of "@Autowired" is to avoid getting new instances (i.e., Spring manages the instance(s)).