# I can't catch DataIntegrityViolationException with @Transactional in an update service method

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, junit

This JUnit tests fails

```
 public void shouldFailToEditUserTypeWithoutType() {
    UserType userType = new UserType(null, "dd");
    userType.setType(null);

    Exception exception = assertThrows(NotNullException.class, () -> {
        userTypeService.update(userType, 1L);
        });

    String expectedMessage = USER_MUST_BE_GIVEN;
    String currentMessage = exception.getMessage();

    assertTrue(currentMessage.contains(expectedMessage));
}
```

with this error

```
Expected :class com.ces.domain.service.exceptions.ExistingEntityDataException
Actual   :class org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException
```

but in Service layer I'm handling errors with try/catch statement like that

```
    @Override
    @Transactional
    public UserType update(UserType userType, Long id) {
        try {
            UserType previousUserType = userTypeRepository.getReferenceById(id);
            updateUserTypedata(previousUserType, userType);

            UserType updatedUserType = userTypeRepository.save(previousUserType);

            return updatedUserType;
        } catch (DataIntegrityViolationException error) {
            throw new ExistingEntityDataException(USER_TYPE_ALREADY_EXIST);
        } catch (EntityNotFoundException error) {
            throw new ResourceNotFoundException(USER_TYPE_NOT_EXIST);
        } catch (ConstraintViolationException error) {
            throw new NotNullException(USER_TYPE_CANNOT_BE_NULL);
        }
    }
```

It was expected that the update method catch DataIntegrityViolationException and throw the ExistingEntityDataException to test capture this custom exception and get custom message

Comment: You have an explanation here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54876448/how-to-catch-hibernate-constraintviolationexception-or-spring-dataintegrityviol?rq=2
To explain it shortly, your code doesn't throw that exception, it comes from Spring proxy mechanism.