# Failed to execute junit5 tests with dependency management with spring boot gradle plugin

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, kotlin, junit5, spring-boot-gradle-plugin

In my project based on gradle and kotlin I have some sub module. Build configugration for it module (build.gradle.kts):

```
plugins {
    java
    kotlin("jvm")
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.1.5.RELEASE"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.0.7.RELEASE"
}

dependencies {

    compile("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.3.31")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")

    testCompile("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.3.31")
    testCompile("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.3.31")
    testCompile("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.3.31")

    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.4.2")
    testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.4.2")
}
```

I try to run some simple test in this module

Simple class:

```
class Hello {
    fun hello(): String {
        return "hello"
    }
}
```

Simple test for it:

```
class HelloTest {
    @Test
    fun test() {
        Assertions.assertEquals(Hello().hello(), "hello")
    }
}
```

When i'm trying to run test i get error:

```
Jun 12, 2019 2:58:31 PM org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher handleThrowable
WARNING: TestEngine with ID 'junit-jupiter' failed to execute tests
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.tryToLoadClass(Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/junit/platform/commons/function/Try;
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.support.OpenTest4JAndJUnit4AwareThrowableCollector.createAbortedExecutionPredicate(OpenTest4JAndJUnit4AwareThrowableCollector.java:40)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.support.OpenTest4JAndJUnit4AwareThrowableCollector.<clinit>(OpenTest4JAndJUnit4AwareThrowableCollector.java:30)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.support.JupiterThrowableCollectorFactory.createThrowableCollector(JupiterThrowableCollectorFactory.java:34)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:68)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:220)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$6(DefaultLauncher.java:188)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:202)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:181)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:128)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.processAllTestClasses(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:102)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.access$000(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:82)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.stop(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:78)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.stop(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:61)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:32)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.stop(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.stop(TestWorker.java:132)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:175)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:404)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:rest:test'.
> No tests found for given includes: [ua.company.app.Hello](filter.includeTestsMatching)
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
BUILD FAILED in 1s
4 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 2 up-to-date
No tests found for given includes: [ua.company.app.Hello](filter.includeTestsMatching)
```

But if remove **id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.0.7.RELEASE"** from my build config and will use version of spring boot like this **compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:2.1.5.RELEASE")** test runs correctly.

Spring dependency management brokes my junit5 tests. Please can anyone explain why this is happening and how to solve the problem? Thanks!

Comment: What is io.spring.dependency-management?

Comment: https://github.com/spring-gradle-plugins/dependency-management-plugin and guide https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.0.RELEASE/gradle-plugin/reference/html/#packaging-executable-and-normal

Comment: Oh I see. I don't use Gradle but I knew that Sam Brannen is working on the JUnit5 integration. Have a look here: https://github.com/sbrannen/junit5-demo Hope this may help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gradle 5 JUnit BOM and Spring Boot Incorrect Versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54598484/gradle-5-junit-bom-and-spring-boot-incorrect-versions)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would appear that adding Spring Dependency Management changes some of the transitive dependencies for your junit-jupiter dependencies.

Your declared junit version (5.4.2) depends on junit-platform-commons 1.4.2, but when you add Spring Dependency Management it is changing the commons version from 1.4.2 to 1.3.2. This is why you are receiving the NoSuchMethodError since that method was added in version four!

Here's two solutions I can think of:

1) (I recommend this) Drop your declared junit version and let Spring Dependency Management handle everything for junit:

```
testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api")
testRuntime("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine")
```

2) Declare the transitive dependency versions for junit (this would allow you to carry on using version 5.4.2 if this is a must-have)

```
testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.4.2")
testImplementation("org.junit.platform:junit-platform-commons:1.4.2")
testRuntime("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.4.2")
testRuntime("org.junit.platform:junit-platform-engine:1.4.2")
```