# Wrong version of JUnit in dependencies

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot, junit, junit5

I want to run JUnit 5.4+ tests on my Spring Boot app so that I can use the @Order annotation on my tests. However, Maven resolves my POM to 5.3.2 regardless of what I try.
I've tried including all the dependencies I can think of manually, but then I end up with a mess of mismatched versions. I also tried clearing my entire ~/.m2/repository folder and rebuilding the tree, same results.

Relevant parts of mvn dependency:tree

```
[INFO] +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:jar:5.5.0:test
[INFO] |  +- org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:jar:1.1.0:test
[INFO] |  +- org.opentest4j:opentest4j:jar:1.2.0:test
[INFO] |  \- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-commons:jar:1.3.2:test
[INFO] +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:jar:5.5.0:test
[INFO] |  +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:jar:5.3.2:test
[INFO] |  \- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:jar:5.3.2:test
[INFO] |     \- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-engine:jar:1.3.2:test
```

Part of the pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>junit</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
...
<plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.1</version>
            </plugin>
...
```

Where does the 5.3.2 come from?

Comment: Can you post the error you have?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gradle 5 JUnit BOM and Spring Boot Incorrect Versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54598484/gradle-5-junit-bom-and-spring-boot-incorrect-versions)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add this line to your the properties in your Maven `pom.xml`:

```
<junit-jupiter.version>5.5.0</junit-jupiter.version>
```

this will control the dependencies defined in dependency management within the spring boot poms (`org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies`).

---

The reason is: that `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies` include `junit-bom`

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-bom</artifactId>
    <version>${junit-jupiter.version}</version>
    <type>pom</type>
    <scope>import</scope>
  </dependency>
```

per default `junit-jupiter.version` is `5.3.2`. So as long as you not change `junit-jupiter.version`, this bom will define that all not explicit listed dependencies (for example `org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params`) are of the version defined in `org.junit:junit-bom:5.3.2`

Comment: Hi @Ralph I get the following error for my code, what to do about it. dependencies.dependency.version' for org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:jar must be a valid version but is '${junit-jupiter.version}'.

Comment: @AnanthuKKumar: you need to specifiy the property `<junit-jupiter.version>` (the second line in my anser)