# Junit 5 Cannot Find Tests (Spring Boot)

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, junit5

I have created a Spring Boot 2.2.6 application through Spring Initilizr which includes JUnit 5.6. I'm using the generated pom.xml along with some additional dependencies and Intellij IDEA 2020.1 as my IDE.

I have created a very simple test just to see if tests work:

```
package com.hua.geoutils;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;

@SpringBootTest
class GeoUtilsTest
{

    @Test
    public void testSplitBoundingBox()
    {
        Assertions.assertEquals(1,1);
    }
}
```

I execute `mvn test spring-boot:run` and on the test lifecycle I get this:

```
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.2:test (default-test) @ atlantis-rest ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
```

It seems that maven doesn't even detect that tests exist and I can't understand why. Any ideas on what is going wrong here ?

**EDIT:**

Here is my pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.hua</groupId>
    <artifactId>atlantis-rest</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>atlantis-rest</name>
    <description>Atlantis REST Web Service</description>
    <!-- <packaging>war</packaging> -->

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20190722</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
            <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.2</version>
            <!-- <type>bundle</type> -->
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.recombee/api-client -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.recombee</groupId>
            <artifactId>api-client</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-quartz</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-session-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.restdocs</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-restdocs-mockmvc</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.asciidoctor</groupId>
                <artifactId>asciidoctor-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.5.8</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-docs</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>process-asciidoc</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <backend>html</backend>
                            <doctype>book</doctype>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.restdocs</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-restdocs-asciidoctor</artifactId>
                        <version>${spring-restdocs.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <!-- <configuration>
                    <executable>true</executable>
                </configuration> -->
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: What package is the annotation `@Test` from?

Comment: @Nikolas edited to include my imports

Comment: Do you have added a dependency to junit-jupiter-engine?

Comment: @khmarbaise Checked it , junit-jupiter-engine 5.5.2 is marked as an external dependency so yes.

Comment: Please show your pom.xml. With high probability the problem is in there.

Comment: @johanneslink edited to include pom.xml

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Taking https://info.michael-simons.eu/2018/06/18/maven-use-junit-5-with-spring-boot-for-unit-and-integration-tests/ as a starting point I recommend to add the jupiter-engine as an explicit dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Alternatively, you can include `junit-jupiter` which is an aggregate component instead of `junit-jupiter-api`. `junit-jupiter` contains the API, the engine and the parameterized tests component.

BTW, if you want to change the version of JUnit with spring boot you have to do add this to your porperties:

```
<junit-jupiter.version>5.6.0</junit-jupiter.version>
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/57055578/32352 for more explanation

Comment: Adding just the property solved the issue. After that each testing class must be marked with `@SpringBootApplication` and `@SpringBootTest` annotations. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You are using both JUnit4 (`Assert`) and JUnit 5 (`@Test`). Originally Maven will try to decide which provider is needed to run tests and somehow JUnit4 was chosen.

Edit tests to use JUnit5 (a.k.a Juipiter) Assertions API. Change `org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(...)` to `org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals(....)`

And don't forget change `org.junit.Assert.*` occurrences to `org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*` in all test files.

Comment: Nice catch , I changed the imports but that didn't solve my issue. But I'm going to edit post since your observation is correct.

Comment: Just using JUnit 4 assertions does not influence Maven in its choice of test framework. It’s the dependencies and surefire plug-in configuration that does it.