# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/test/context/TestContextAnnotationUtils

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, gradle, junit5

I am setting unit tests with Junit5 and Spring Boot 2 in my Gradle project JAVA 11. I am stuck with this error. I have tried a possible solution available online but am not able to figure out what is causing this.

**Gradle and Spring boot version:**

> classpath
> 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:2.1.8.RELEASE'
> distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6.4-bin.zip

```
Test ignored.

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/test/context/TestContextAnnotationUtils

at org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.OverrideAutoConfigurationContextCustomizerFactory.createContextCustomizer(OverrideAutoConfigurationContextCustomizerFactory.java:41)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.getContextCustomizers(AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.java:404)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.buildMergedContextConfiguration(AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.java:376)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.buildDefaultMergedContextConfiguration(AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.java:312)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.buildMergedContextConfiguration(AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.java:265)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.buildTestContext(AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.java:108)
at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper.buildTestContext(SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper.java:98)
at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.<init>(TestContextManager.java:139)
at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.<init>(TestContextManager.java:124)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExtensionValuesStore.lambda$getOrComputeIfAbsent$0(ExtensionValuesStore.java:81)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExtensionValuesStore$MemoizingSupplier.get(ExtensionValuesStore.java:182)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExtensionValuesStore.getOrComputeIfAbsent(ExtensionValuesStore.java:84)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExtensionValuesStore.getOrComputeIfAbsent(ExtensionValuesStore.java:88)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.NamespaceAwareStore.getOrComputeIfAbsent(NamespaceAwareStore.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.getTestContextManager(SpringExtension.java:202)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.beforeAll(SpringExtension.java:76)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeBeforeAllCallbacks$7(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:359)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeBeforeAllCallbacks(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:359)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.before(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:189)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.before(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:78)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:132)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:248)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$5(DefaultLauncher.java:211)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:226)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:199)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:132)
at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:71)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:220)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:53)
Suppressed: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/test/context/TestContextAnnotationUtils
    at org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.OverrideAutoConfigurationContextCustomizerFactory.createContextCustomizer(OverrideAutoConfigurationContextCustomizerFactory.java:41)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.getContextCustomizers(AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.java:404)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.buildMergedContextConfiguration(AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.java:376)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.buildDefaultMergedContextConfiguration(AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.java:312)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.buildMergedContextConfiguration(AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.java:265)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.buildTestContext(AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.java:108)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper.buildTestContext(SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper.java:98)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.<init>(TestContextManager.java:139)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.<init>(TestContextManager.java:124)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExtensionValuesStore.lambda$getOrComputeIfAbsent$0(ExtensionValuesStore.java:81)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExtensionValuesStore$MemoizingSupplier.get(ExtensionValuesStore.java:182)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExtensionValuesStore.remove(ExtensionValuesStore.java:98)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.NamespaceAwareStore.remove(NamespaceAwareStore.java:73)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.afterAll(SpringExtension.java:88)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeAfterAllCallbacks$13(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:425)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeAfterAllCallbacks$14(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:425)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeAfterAllCallbacks(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:425)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.after(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:213)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.after(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:78)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:145)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:145)
    ... 27 more



 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.test.context.TestContextAnnotationUtils
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
... 51 more
```

**Test Class:**

```
 @ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
 //@ContextConfiguration(classes = {HealthCheckService.class})
 //@WebMvcTest
 @AutoConfigureMockMvc
 @SpringBootTest
 @Tag("healthCheck")
 class HealthCheckServiceTest {

      @Autowired
      private MockMvc mockMvc;
      @InjectMocks
      private HealthCheckService healthCheckService;

 }
```

**build.gradle**

```
// FOR TESTS
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test") {
        exclude group: "org.junit.vintage", module: "junit-vintage-engine"
        exclude group: "junit", module: "junit"
    }
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test-autoconfigure:2.4.2'
    testCompile "org.assertj:assertj-core:3.16.1"
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.6.0'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.6.0'
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:5.6.0'
    testCompile ('org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.6.0')
    implementation group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-context', version: '5.3.3'
    testImplementation 'org.junit.platform:junit-platform-commons:1.5.2'
    testImplementation 'org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher:1.6.1'
    testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-junit-jupiter:3.5.7'
```

Comment: Is it possible to provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? It's hard to tell what's missing. Issues I can see so far: mixing `testCompile` and `testImplemention`, `spring-boot-test-autoconfigure` is `compile` scope rather than `testImplementation` and I think shouldn't be provided at all, `spring-context` seems superfluous since you're using Spring Boot ...

Answer (score 5):

`TestContextAnnotationUtils` was introduced in Spring Framework 5.3.0 in the `spring-test` module.

Since `OverrideAutoConfigurationContextCustomizerFactory` (from Spring Boot Test) fails due to the absence of `TestContextAnnotationUtils` in the classpath, it appears that you have a more recent version of Spring Boot and older versions of modules from the Spring Framework (e.g., `spring-test`).

In general, you are mixing a number of potentially incompatible dependencies in your build (for example, the various JUnit Platform 1.5.2/1.6.1 and JUnit Jupiter 5.6.0 artifacts).

When using Spring Boot, you should not be declaring dependencies with explicit versions like that. Rather, you should rely on Spring Boot's support for managing the versions. See this answer for details: [Gradle 5 JUnit BOM and Spring Boot Incorrect Versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54598484/gradle-5-junit-bom-and-spring-boot-incorrect-versions/54605523#54605523)

Without seeing a *Minimal Reproducible Example*, we cannot help much more than to say... please clean up your dependency management and rely on Spring Boot to manage the versions.