# Junit testing spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, maven, testing, junit

I want to start unit testing for my spring-boot application with Intelliji

code

```
class BookingControllerTest {
    private MockMvc mvc;
    @Test
    void countBookings() throws Exception {
        RequestBuilder request = MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/bookings/count");
        MvcResult result = mvc.perform(request).andReturn();
        assertEquals(3,3);

    }
}
```

whenever I start my test I got this error

```
WARNING: TestEngine with ID 'junit-vintage' failed to discover tests
org.junit.platform.commons.JUnitException: Failed to parse version of junit:junit: 4.13.2
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.JUnit4VersionCheck.parseVersion(JUnit4VersionCheck.java:54)
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.JUnit4VersionCheck.checkSupported(JUnit4VersionCheck.java:37)
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.JUnit4VersionCheck.checkSupported(JUnit4VersionCheck.java:32)
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.VintageTestEngine.discover(VintageTestEngine.java:61)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.discoverEngineRoot(DefaultLauncher.java:177)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.discoverRoot(DefaultLauncher.java:164)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:128)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:71)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)


java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc.perform(org.springframework.test.web.servlet.RequestBuilder)" because "this.mvc" is null

    at Booking.controllers.BookingControllerTest.countBookings(BookingControllerTest.java:26)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:628)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:117)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$7(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:184)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:180)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:127)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:68)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:229)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$6(DefaultLauncher.java:197)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:211)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:191)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:128)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:71)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)


Process finished with exit code -1
```

you can find here my pom.xml file which contains all my dependencies in case there is something wrong or something I need to download / delete/add or change version!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>Booking</groupId>
    <artifactId>Booking</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Booking</name>
    <description>BookingSystem</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>18</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.15</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <!--<exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>

                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>-->
        </dependency>




        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${project.parent.version}</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>17</source>
                    <target>17</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <finalName>booking</finalName>
    </build>

</project>
```

I tried to change the version of my Junit and restarted my Intellij( invalid chache) but nothing happend and the same error kept appearing
can anyone tell me what is the problem please ?

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67563862/testengine-with-id-junit-vintage-failed-to-discover-tests-junitexception-fa

Answer (score 0):

According to `java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc.perform(org.springframework.test.web.servlet.RequestBuilder)" because "this.mvc" is null` your field `private MockMvc mvc;` was not initialized. You need to initialize it.

You can follow https://spring.io/guides/gs/testing-web/ for example.

TLDR;
Try adding these annotations to initialize it.

```
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
class BookingControllerTest {
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc;
    @Test
    void countBookings() throws Exception {
        RequestBuilder request = MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/bookings/count");
        MvcResult result = mvc.perform(request).andReturn();
        assertEquals(3,3);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Spring boot 2.x works with JUnit 5
Your exception clearly states there you're using JUnit 4 somewhere.
So the first step is cleaning up the dependencies.

In general you can add to `pom.xml`

```
 <dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
     <scope>test</scope>
 </dependency>
```

But again, since JUnit 4 appears in the test classpath, make sure you understand where does it come from (analyze with `mvn dependency:tree`, for example) and eliminate it.

Then, as the second exception states - you're trying to use Mock MVC but you don't run Spring at all.

A minimal setup will look like this:

```
@WebMvcTest(BookingController.class)
class BookingControllerTest {
    @Autowired  // injecting mock mvc engine into the test 
    private MockMvc mvc;
    @Test
    void countBookings() throws Exception {
        RequestBuilder request = MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/bookings/count");
        MvcResult result = mvc.perform(request).andReturn();
        assertEquals(3,3); // you should assert the result of execution with  .andExpect(...);
           

    }
}
```

An example of a test like that (from [this article](https://spring.io/guides/gs/testing-web/)):

```java
@WebMvcTest
public class WebLayerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    public void shouldReturnDefaultMessage() throws Exception {
        this.mockMvc.perform(get("/")).andDo(print()).andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().string(containsString("Hello, World")));
    }
}
```