# IntelliJ No tests were found with exit code 0

Tags: java, selenium, unit-testing, intellij-idea, automated-tests

Just started a QA Automation tester course and I am having some problems with IntelliJ. When I am trying to run a test I get Process finished with exit code 0 and no tests were found.

```
public class MyStoreTest {
private WebDriver driver;

@BeforeEach
public void beforeEach() {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "src/test/resources/drivers/chromedriver.exe");
    this.driver = new ChromeDriver();
    this.driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(16));
    this.driver.get("https://mystore-testlab.coderslab.pl/index.php");
}

@Test
public void MyStoreTest() {
    MyStoreMainPage MyStoreMainPage = new MyStoreMainPage(driver);
    MyStoreMainPage.clickSignIn();

    MyStoreAuthenticationPage authenticationPage = new MyStoreAuthenticationPage(driver);
    String email =  "oetuomldfaacfducoz@bvhrk.com";
    String password = "1992Dawid";
    authenticationPage.submitSignIn(email , password);

    MyStoreAddAnAddressPage AddAnAddress = new MyStoreAddAnAddressPage(driver);
    AddressData AddressData = new AddressData()
            .setAddress("Ul.Pulawska")
            .setZip("02-508")
            .setCity("Warszawa");

    AddAnAddress.AddAnAddress(AddressData);

    MyStoreMyAccountPage myAccountPage = new MyStoreMyAccountPage(driver);
    assertTrue(myAccountPage.isAddressSuccessfullyAdded());
}
```

}

How can I understand why it can find no test?
I am would be really grateful for any answers

Other than no tests found I get

org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher handleThrowable
WARNING: TestEngine with ID 'junit-vintage' failed to discover tests
org.junit.platform.commons.JUnitException: Failed to parse version of junit:junit: 4.13.2
at org.junit.vintage.engine.JUnit4VersionCheck.parseVersion(JUnit4VersionCheck.java:54)
at org.junit.vintage.engine.JUnit4VersionCheck.checkSupported(JUnit4VersionCheck.java:37)
at org.junit.vintage.engine.JUnit4VersionCheck.checkSupported(JUnit4VersionCheck.java:32)
at org.junit.vintage.engine.VintageTestEngine.discover(VintageTestEngine.java:61)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.discoverEngineRoot(DefaultLauncher.java:177)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.discoverRoot(DefaultLauncher.java:164)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:128)
at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:71)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)

wrz 15, 2022 12:31:10 AM org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher handleThrowable
WARNING: TestEngine with ID 'junit-jupiter' failed to discover tests
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/junit/jupiter/api/io/CleanupMode
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.JupiterTestEngine.discover(JupiterTestEngine.java:66)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.discoverEngineRoot(DefaultLauncher.java:177)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.discoverRoot(DefaultLauncher.java:164)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:128)
at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:71)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.junit.jupiter.api.io.CleanupMode
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
... 10 more

Maybe the problem is in my java classes?

```
public class AddressData {

private String Address;
private String City;
private String Zip;

public String getAddress() {
    return Address;
}

public AddressData setAddress(String Address) {
    this.Address = Address;
    return this;
}

public String getCity() {
    return City;
}

public AddressData setCity(String City) {
    this.City = City;
    return this;
}

public String getZip() {
    return Zip;
}

public AddressData setZip(String Zip) {
    this.Zip = Zip;
    return this;
}
```

}

```
public class MyStoreAddAnAddressPage {
public WebDriver driver;
public MyStoreAddAnAddressPage(WebDriver driver) {
    this.driver = driver;
}
public void AddAnAddress(AddressData AddressData) {

    WebElement AddressInput = driver.findElement(By.name("address1"));
    AddressInput.sendKeys(AddressData.getAddress());
    WebElement CityInput = driver.findElement(By.name("city"));
    CityInput.sendKeys(AddressData.getCity());
    WebElement ZipInput = driver.findElement(By.name("postcode"));
    ZipInput.sendKeys(AddressData.getZip());

    WebElement saveButton = this.driver.findElement(
            By.name("submitAddress")
    );
    saveButton.click();
}
```

}

```
public class MyStoreAuthenticationPage {

@FindBy(css = "href#log.in.to.your.customer.account")
private WebElement signIn;

@FindBy(name = "email")
private WebElement emailInput;

@FindBy(name = "password")
private WebElement passwordInput;

@FindBy(id = "submit-login")
private WebElement signInButton;
private WebDriver driver;


public MyStoreAuthenticationPage(WebDriver driver) {
    PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
}

public void submitSignIn(String email, String password) {
    emailInput.sendKeys(email);
    passwordInput.sendKeys(password);
    signInButton.click();
}
```

}

```
public class MyStoreMainPage {
public WebDriver driver;
public MyStoreMainPage(WebDriver driver) {
    this.driver = driver;
}
public void clickSignIn() {
    WebElement signIn = this.driver.findElement(
            By.cssSelector("href#log.in.to.your.customer.account")
    );
    signIn.click();
}
```

}

```
public class MyStoreMyAccountPage {
public WebDriver driver;

public MyStoreMyAccountPage(WebDriver driver) {
    this.driver = driver;
}

public boolean isAddressSuccessfullyAdded() {
    WebElement confirmationPanel = this.driver.findElement(
            By.cssSelector("article.alert.alert-success")
    );
    String panelText = confirmationPanel.getText();

   return panelText.equals("Address successfully added!");
}
```

}

Comment: "When I am trying to run a test" How *exactly* are you doing this?

Comment: Also please show the import statements.

Comment: Add @SpringBootTest annotation  to mystoretest class. Then may be it will work.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67563862/testengine-with-id-junit-vintage-failed-to-discover-tests-junitexception-fa

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score -1):

Hard to say without more information but it's possible that your run configuration is incorrect. Beside the test in the editor, there should be a play button. Try running it that way for a brand new run configuration.

[image]

If the button isn't visible, try invalidating caches and restarting the IDE as you may be missing some imports that the editor should detect when it restarts.