# JUnit5 Order Execution - OrderAnnotation Ignored

Tags: java, junit

UPDATE:  I should have included the original POM file (below), and the fact that I did attempt solutions from [JUnit's @TestMethodOrder annotation not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54947645/junits-testmethodorder-annotation-not-working/54959532#54959532)

---

What I'm Trying to Do:  Run JUnit tests in a specific order.

What's wrong

- Current order notation is incorrect or ignored.  With each run the order randomly changes (no changes in code).  I have ~ 5 additional methods to test, and the test order becomes more important.
- Used https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/ section 2.9 as guide.

Environment:

- JUnit 5.6.0
- Java 16
- Netbeans IDE with Maven

---

```java
package com.riverrat.recipebook;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertTrue;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertFalse;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.MethodOrderer.OrderAnnotation;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Order;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.TestMethodOrder;

@TestMethodOrder(OrderAnnotation.class)
public class IngredientListTest {
    //do stuff
    
    @Test
    @Order(1)
    public void testIsEmpty(){//do stuff}
    
    @Test
    @Order(2)
    public void testAddBacon(){//do stuff}
    
    @Test
    @Order(3)
    public void testDeleteBaconByObject(){//do stuff}
    
    @Test
    @Order(4)
    public void testDeleteBaconByInt(){//do stuff}
    
    @Test
    @Order(5)
    public void testLoadAllIngredients(){//do stuff}
}
```

Current POM

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.riverrat</groupId>
    <artifactId>RecipeBook</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>16</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>16</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
            
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
  
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-params</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    
</project>
```

Comment: This is already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54959532/5662508

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JUnit's @TestMethodOrder annotation not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54947645/junits-testmethodorder-annotation-not-working)

Comment: I should have mentioned I tried that post first.  I've updated my post to include the POM.  Its the default that was built with the Netbeans/Maven project, plus adding an additional dependency based on https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-build-maven