# Not able to use @MethodSource in @ParameterizedTest

Tags: java, testing, junit5

I am trying to create a parameterised test with a method source. Following is the code :

```
import java.util.stream.Stream;
import org.junit.jupiter.params.ParameterizedTest;
import org.junit.jupiter.params.provider.MethodSource;

class ABCTest {

    @ParameterizedTest
    @MethodSource("abc")
    void testABC(String word) {
        System.out.println(word);
    }

    static Stream<String> abc() {
        return Stream.of("a1",
                "b2");
    }

}
```

But this doesn't work; while trying to run the test case, I am

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'java.lang.String[] org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.parseQualifiedMethodName(java.lang.String)'
.
.
.
    Suppressed: org.junit.platform.commons.PreconditionViolationException: Configuration error: You must configure at least one set of arguments for this @ParameterizedTest
        at org.junit.platform.commons.util.Preconditions.condition(Preconditions.java:281)
        at org.junit.jupiter.params.ParameterizedTestExtension.lambda$provideTestTemplateInvocationContexts$5(ParameterizedTestExtension.java:98)
```

Following is my `pom.xml` :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId><hiding_this_intentionally></groupId>
    <artifactId><hiding_this_intentionally></artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>4.3.20-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <modules>
        <module><hiding_this_intentionally></module>
        <module><hiding_this_intentionally></module>
    </modules>

    <parent>
        <groupId><hiding_this_intentionally></groupId>
        <artifactId><hiding_this_intentionally></artifactId>
        <version>1.0.19</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
<!--        Java related properties -->
        <jdk.source.version>17</jdk.source.version>
        <jdk.target.version>17</jdk.target.version>
        <jdk.release.version>17</jdk.release.version>
<!--        Maven related properties -->
        <maven.compiler.plugin.version>3.9.0</maven.compiler.plugin.version>
        <maven.deploy.plugin.version>2.8.2</maven.deploy.plugin.version>
        <maven.shade.plugin.version>3.3.0</maven.shade.plugin.version>
        <maven.javadoc.skip>true</maven.javadoc.skip>

        <userservice-model.version>2.0.8</userservice-model.version>
        <vault-model.version>0.0.66</vault-model.version>
        <ablaze.version>3.0.15</ablaze.version>

        <aspectj.maven.plugin.version>1.13.1</aspectj.maven.plugin.version>

        <json-rules.version>1.0.11</json-rules.version>
        <zjsonpatch.version>0.4.3</zjsonpatch.version>
        <lombok.version>1.18.22</lombok.version>
        <lombok.maven.version>1.18.20.0</lombok.maven.version>
        <junit.version>4.12</junit.version>
        <guava.version>30.1.1-jre</guava.version>
        <h2.version>1.4.191</h2.version>
        <!-- Sonar-JaCoCo properties -->
        <sonar.java.coveragePlugin>jacoco</sonar.java.coveragePlugin>
        <sonar.dynamicAnalysis>reuseReports</sonar.dynamicAnalysis>
        <sonar.jacoco.reportPaths>${project.basedir}/../target/jacoco.exec</sonar.jacoco.reportPaths>
        <sonar.language>java</sonar.language>
        <sonar.buildbreaker.skip>true</sonar.buildbreaker.skip>
        <giftcard.provider.model.version>1.0.3</giftcard.provider.model.version>
        <log4j.to.slf4j.version>2.8.2</log4j.to.slf4j.version>
        <jersey.guava.version>2.6</jersey.guava.version>
        <clearspring.analytics.stream.version>2.9.5</clearspring.analytics.stream.version>
        <sonar.qualitygate.wait>false</sonar.qualitygate.wait>

        <gpp.aerospike.version>4.1.8</gpp.aerospike.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.flipkart.ranger</groupId>
                <artifactId>ranger</artifactId>
                <version>0.6.3</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
            <artifactId>hbase-shaded-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>${guava.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-module-afterburner</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.raven.dropwizard</groupId>
            <artifactId>dropwizard-jmxmp</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.raskasa.metrics</groupId>
            <artifactId>metrics-okhttp</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
            <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.clearspring.analytics</groupId>
            <artifactId>stream</artifactId>
            <version>${clearspring.analytics.stream.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.appform.rules</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-rules</artifactId>
            <version>${json-rules.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.flipkart.zjsonpatch</groupId>
            <artifactId>zjsonpatch</artifactId>
            <version>${zjsonpatch.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>${lombok.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
            <artifactId>dropwizard-jackson</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-to-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.to.slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.bundles.repackaged</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-guava</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.guava.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.reflections</groupId>
            <artifactId>reflections</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Testing -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-params</artifactId>
            <version>5.9.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>${h2.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
            <artifactId>dropwizard-testing</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.deploy.plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skip>false</skip>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                <artifactId>lombok-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>delombok</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <version>${lombok.maven.version}</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.compiler.plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${jdk.source.version}</source>
                    <target>${jdk.target.version}</target>
                    <release>${jdk.release.version}</release>
                    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                    <debug>false</debug>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>docker</id>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

Can someone help me here?

Tried changing the version of junit-jupiter-params as suggested in [NoSuchMethodError: org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.tryToLoadClass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53926264/nosuchmethoderror-org-junit-platform-commons-util-reflectionutils-trytoloadclas), still didn't work

Comment: Can you include the whole test class?

Comment: You probably have something else going on. Your code as it looks fine.

Comment: The error message suggests a lib version mismatch. Please add your full Maven pom.

Comment: added full pom.xml file @johanneslink

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @johanneslink, you have a lib version mismatch. You are using `JUnit4` framework (specifically `JUnit 4.12`), while `@ParameterizedTest` annotation (as well as `junit-jupiter-params` dependency in your `pom.xml`) belongs to `Junit5` framework.

To include `JUnit5` into your project, remove the `JUnit4` dependency and add the following to your `pom.xml`:

```html
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
    <version>5.10.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
    <version>5.10.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-params</artifactId>
    <version>5.10.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

[Here](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/junit-platform.html) is the guide for setting up JUnit5

Note that it is important to maintain the same versions of dependecies even when you are using `JUnit5`. For example, including `junit-jupiter-engine 5.10.0` with `junit-jupiter-params 5.9.2` will result in non-working code.

Additionaly, there is a [JUnit5 Aggregator](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter/5.10.0), which is a shorthand for including three dependencies listed above, using it will make your pom less cluttered and leave out burden of checking that the versions of all three dependencies are the same.

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
<artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
<version>5.10.0</version>
<scope>test</scope>
```

Also note that there is a way to create parameterized tests with `JUnit4` ([see here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/junit/junit_parameterized_test.htm)), but I recommend to upgrade to `JUnit5` anyway, because it is a more capable and easier to use framework overall.

Answer (score -1):

For `@ParameterizedTest` in combination with `@MethodSource` you need to return a Stream of Arguments `Stream<Arguments>` from your method. `Arguments` is located in package `package org.junit.jupiter.params.provider`

For Example:

```
private static Stream<Arguments> validPurchasePlatformGenerator() {
    return Arrays.stream(PurchasePlatform.values())
        .filter(purchasePlatform -> !purchasePlatform.equals(PurchasePlatform.WEB))
        .map(Arguments::of);
}
```

and then

```
@ParameterizedTest
@DisplayName("Some DisplayText")
@MethodSource("validPurchasePlatformGenerator")
void purchaseValid_shouldReturnValidResult(PurchasePlatform purchasePlatform) { 
    // test code
}
```

If you want to use just plain string, you can also use `@ValueSource` instead of `@MethodSource` which would make more sense for your provided test.

For Example

```
@ParameterizedTest
@ValueSource(strings = { "a1", "a2" })
void testABC(String word) {
    System.out.println(word);
}
```

Comment: the example I quoted was an oversimplified demo of what I intent. I want to use `Arguments` of more complex Objects, but getting same error while trying that so cannot simply use `@ValueSource`

Comment: Using `Stream<Arguments>` is not _required_. It could be a `Stream<String>` or `String[]`, since the test method has only a single `String` parameter. See [the documentation](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org.junit.jupiter.params/org/junit/jupiter/params/provider/MethodSource.html).